# Which is the maximum URI length?

Tags: http, browser, uri

A customer would like to have the headlines of articles used as URLs. The database field of the headline is a varchar(512), so in the worst case I would have

```
http://+domain with 19 chars+512 chars+.html
```

means 543 chars if I ignore the categories (which could be nested and theoretically be of endless length).
I read that on server-side there is a limit of 4000 chars, but there may be browsers which are limited to 256(!) chars. On which information can I rely?

Comment: sorry, I searched for that but didn't received this question. Thanks for the link.